# As GM, how to implement an enemy that erases the PC's memory

Tags: gm-techniques, system-agnostic, encounter-design

I like the idea of an innocent-looking enemy, or even just a zone, in some dangerous place, that slowly erases the memories of anyone near it, whether randomly or starting from the newest memories.
The interesting part would be that even if you knew about the danger of amnesia, you start forgetting that danger also and thus you don't realize you're exposing yourself to more and more danger, and may decide to just relax, until maybe much later you forget how to fight, speak or even breathe ?

That could make a great story, but how to implement it in the context of a RPG?

I'm open to many ideas, whether players/PCs know about it beforehand ("The townsfolk said...", "Ok guys, in this campaign, you will face...") or have to deduce what's happening.
Do I, as the DM, give elements that become contradictory as the memories go ("No, I've never said this!") ?

Do they start the campaign already not knowing anything, therefore aligning the PC's and the players memory? But what if that happens again later?

Do I use NPCs and other *deus ex machina* for info/saving?

Maybe the forgetting could be avoidable, in a sort of mini-game to fight for some of your memories, what about cards representing memories, clues to put together ?

Do I plan sessions every 30 years, so that the players themselves will have forgotten ? (ok, maybe not this one)

It would be great to see the actual players suddenly realizing what's happening out-of-character, but if it's impossible, I'm open to variations.

These are just my brainstormed ideas, I want to understand how to effectively design an encounter as described.

Comment: Nothing in particular, if an answer requires a specific system, I'm fine with that and would like to know about it too.

Comment: "Forget how to breath" is not quite how the central nervous system works, in humans.  Your concept doesn't make a good story, Speculative-Fiction-wise, since it clashes with the how breathing just works: you don't need how to remember to do it.  (Unlike, for example, your wedding anniversary where you need to use memory to recall it).

Comment: This question needs editing. Asking for experience is ok. Asking for suggested design ideas is unlikely to generate many good responses here, and would be better suited to other websites -- where, for example, back and forth conversation is more practical, such as Facebook's RPG Design Network Group.

Comment: I think this question is an edge case, but strictly fine, so I vote to leave it open, but will add my close vote if it attracts several bad answers —from review.

Comment: Great concept and I'm pretty sure there are plenty of experience DMs who can and/or provide lived experience on managing such a creature at the table, both while role-playing and managing it practically with the players - but I do think there needs to be more focus, i.e. This is my idea... and ask for answers from DMs/players with lived experience.

Comment: This question needs to describe the system it's for. I know how I would run this in a system like Dungeon World, but trying to run it like that in another system would be weird or even impossible (e.g. not every system has XP like DW).

Comment: Some systems **have rules for this**, such as Call of Cthulhu, in many others this is plainly opinion-based.

Comment: Well I wish I had gotten answers about how to do in in Dungeon world and Call of Ctuhlhu then, before the question was closed. Should I have just asked one separate question for every way I could think of ?

Comment: @LogicalKip yes, you ask about a single system for such things, not system agnostic, and not several.

Answer (score 1):

### I can give you little to none feedback **strictly** to your question, but what I can give you is propably better: an Inspiration

Link to the story: [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AllThingsDND/comments/gjk4eb/how_my_dm_turned_our_four_horsemen_campaign_on/)

It is a story about beginning of new campaign for a group of players, and their interactions with a false hydra. It is way too long to post here, so I will only summarize it here, but it does not compare to original.

> Party enters a small city, that is known to host a disease; many people died already, and many more are suffering. Empty houses, people walking around sometimes twitch nerwously or look terrified, only to calm themselves down etc., party stay in Inn. They pay for lodging to the barman and his wife, meet with local physician, do some investigating, all good. Next day they walk down from their rooms, and pay barmaid for next day. Everything starts to crumble when one player asks for her husband, and she says she's single. Players find letters from nonexisting people, some notes on passing days and fight with the malaise. And an idea to control rising unrest in city. To give physican time to work on a cure. To make them forget. They find description of false hydra, putrid being, it's song  when heared make you forget everything about false hydra's existence, even if it is right in front of you. That if a person is devoured by false hydra, so are memories of this person, making it like that one never existed in the first place, gnawing on human psyche for inexplainable things, like empty houses, like that eerie feeling of danger you cannot dispose of, after all, everything is ok. Then they confront the physician, after that comes a boss fight.

I hope you will find this helpfull.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, were you the DM or a player for this one?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast No, I just heard this story on youtube, but thought it would be a good one to share here.

Answer (score -1):

A minor version of this arose on the popular web series Critical Role Campaign 2.

> This occured as a sub-plot of an island called Rumblecusp that the player characters visited.

Overview

> The characters became aware of the gradual threat it posed, and were able to deal with the issue before it caused very substantial issues for them -- but it was a substantial threat and there were a lot of NPCs that were heavily impacted and had been there for years.

Details

> The players were required to make wisdom saving throws each night, against slowly increasing DCs. Once they realised what was happening, they role played reminding each other who they where as an attempt to lower the DC -- I've not seen confirmation from the GM that this worked, but knowing how he's ruled other things, it is likely it did. They only failed the checks a couple of times, and the worst mechanical impact they suffered was the loss of randomised items -- which was also something they saw happen to NPCs (They found some lost items).

> Matt also described their loss of memory in game. The implication was that the threat of memory loss was gradual - slowly creeping up on them. The NPCs had been there longer and served as examples of what the danger was, which helped communicate the danger and threat to the player characters.

You can find all the relevant episodes here:

> https://criticalrole.fandom.com/wiki/Rumblecusp#History

Clicking on each link will give you a synopsis, but they can also be found in full on YouTube.

Comment: While this story arc does protray some similar themes, I don't think this is a good answer to the question. Mainly because it didn't occur to the PCs, but also because this is basically a link-only answer. You don't include information from the show that is essential to answer this question, like how the mechanics worked or what the impact was. If you can [edit] your answer to be more complete it might be a viable answer. As is it will likely be removed.

Comment: @linksassin the players were effected by the memory loss -- not to a major degree, but they all made saving throws against it each night, and a couple of them failed checks, resulting in lost random items. It was presented as a gradual threat yes, but I think also the example of how the threat of it happening impacted the players is still very relevant.

Comment: Mildly annoying that I don't seem to be able to format stuff in spoiler tags.

Comment: Oohhh, if it affects short-term memory first, those spells you re-mem'ed last night you can't remember today. Ouchies.